# What chapters of akame ga kill cover the anime?

Tags: akame-ga-kill

I watched the whole anime and I'm interested in buying the manga where the anime left off. Thank you in advance.

Comment: The anime ended up being original. Episodes 1-18 equal chapters 1-34. Episodes 19-21 cover some stuff (up to chapter 50) and skip many things so start at chapter 35.

Comment: @Sanji any reason you removed this as an Answer and put it as a Comment? Comments are for clarification, this should be posted as an Answer.

Comment: Because I didn't do any research (I already knew the answer) and it was 1 and a half lines long.

Comment: On another note, you're gonna love the Tatsumi X Mine stuff. In the anime it came out of the blue but the manga does a nice job with the buildup.